# Uniqueness thereom and linearly independent solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, determinant

If 
$$y_1=\sin(x^2)$$
$$y_2=\cos(x^2)$$
are linearly independent solutions of 
$$xy''-y'+4x^3y=0$$
the wronskian 
$$W(y_1,y_2)$$
is zero when $x=0$.

Does this contradict the theorem which states that if y1 and y2 are linearly independent solution then their wronskian is not zero ?

Are $y_1$ and $y_2$  still independent when x=0  but the wronskian is zero ?

Are $y_1$ and $y_2$  independent for all values of $x$ but dependent when $x=0$ ?

Is this related to the uniqueness theorem ? how ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2461940/108128

Answer (score 1):

The Wronskian of linearly independent functions may vanish at certain values of $x$ (or whatever variable the functions are in). However, the Wronskian will never be identically zero (i.e. it does not vanish for **all** values of $x$).

See this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian).

Comment: Since the Wronskian is a solution of Adel's equation, it is identically zero or never zero.